# PHP function not callable

Tags: php

The past 3 hours I'm scratching my head with the following problem. My Database class:

```
<?php

class Database {
    private static $_instance = null;

    private $_pdo;


    private function __construct() {
      try {
        $this -> _pdo = new PDO('...'));
      } catch (PDOException $e)
      {
        die($e -> getMessage());
      }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
      if (!isset(self:: $_instance)) {
        self:: $_instance = new Database();
      } else {
        return self:: $_instance;
      }
    }

    public function test($sql) {
      echo $sql;
    }

  }
```

When I call `Database::getInstance()->test('Hello')` I get the following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function test() on a non-object in
>   ...

I checked for proper pdo connection, no problem with that. The output of `var_dump(Database::getInstance())` is NULL.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a return on your `getInstance()`

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if(!isset(self::$_instance))
    {
        self::$_instance = new Database(); //here
    }else
    {
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

instead you should do:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if(!isset(self::$_instance))
    {
        return self::$_instance = new Database();
    }else
    {
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

or:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if(!isset(self::$_instance))
    {
        self::$_instance = new Database();
    }

    return self::$_instance;
}
```